# Updated certificate in GPO not being deployed to Trusted Root Certification Authorities

Tags: group-policy, ssl-certificate

I created a GPO to deploy a new trusted root CA certificate to end-user machines.

This worked correctly and the certificate was deployed. Unfortunately I'd made a mistake with the certificate and I needed to correct it. I created a new certificate file, removed the old one from `Computer\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Public Key Policies\Trusted Root Certification Authorities`, and imported the new one.

The new, correct certificate has a different CN and expiry date, so in effect it's totally different.

When I check an end user's computer certificates, they have the old certificate but not the new one. I managed to get one client to pick up the new certificate by running `gpupdate /force`, but I don't want to have to do this for 500 clients.

Why is this happening? Is there some way to force this change through to all clients?

Comment: Group Policy will refresh every 90 minutes by default. So... you can simply wait it out.

Comment: It has been in place for weeks